# не могу открыть таблицу openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

В начале я скачиваю таблицу с google, затем читаю данные, но выдаётся AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'style'.
Сам код:

```
import openpyxl
load = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Vasya\journal\v2\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    load = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 228, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 443, in bind_all
    self.bind_merged_cells()
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 380, in bind_merged_cells
    self.ws._clean_merge_range(mcr)
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 607, in _clean_merge_range
    mcr.format()
  File "C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\merge.py", line 109, in format
    if side.style is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Если же перед этим в таблице в ручную что-нибудь отредактировать, то ошибка не возвращается.
Естественно я не собираюсь редактировать таблицы в ручную, что мне делать?

Comment: ну а сам код, который вызывает ошибку, где?

Comment: @strawdog, код в вопросе ;)

Comment: @MaxU "затем пытаюсь вытащить из неё определённые данные" ?

Comment: @strawdog, если я правильно понял то чтение данных при помощи `openpyxl` - это `"пытаюсь вытащить из неё определённые данные"`) Error traceback указывает на то, что ошибка возникает в строке `load = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')`

Comment: @strawdog я исправил вопрос

Comment: @Vasya775, а вручную вы редактируете в чем - в Excel? И как открывается свежескачанный с Google файл в Excel - выдаёт ли Excel предупреждения?

Comment: @MaxU, да, я редактирую в Excel. Excel не выдаёт предупреждений, только включается защищённый просмотр.

Comment: @Vasya775, не думаю, что вам смогут помочь без __воспроизводимого__ файла. Можете выложить этот "проблемный" Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы .xlsx содержат еще и sheet(листы):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')                    # откройте файл
# wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx', read_only=True)  # для защищенного просмотра
ws = wb.active                                     # выберите активный лист
# ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(<sheet_name>)          # или по имени sheet_name
```

Теперь уже на выбранном листе ищите нужные вам данные:

```
cell_obj = ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: Проблема в wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx'). Файл не открывается. Таблица скачивается с google sheet, открывается только если я что-нибудь отредактирую вручную.

Comment: похоже ошибка возникает уже в строке `wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')` ;)

Comment: @Vasya775 а так: wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx', read_only=True) откроется?

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо, это решило проблему